# Not getting header back from API Gateway URL

Tags: aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway proxy URL to an internal API. I need to get a customized header "rwd" from the API response and so I have set in the API Gateway's integration response and method response, and I see the header when I test the URL within API Gateway console.

But when I call the API Gateway URL from Postman, or cURL, the header is missing.

Any idea what am I missing in the setup?

[image: Integration response for 200]

[image: Method Response for 200]

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - needed to click on "Deploy API" in the dropdown for changes to take effect. Silly me for missing it!

[image]